# Android onRestoreInstanceState - how to restore objects after screen orientation change?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write my first Android app. I have 3 fragments, each of them has the same UI and it's own object called Rota#number.
I have typical begginers issue: how to keep my objects after screen orientation changed? I'd like to restore Rota1-Rota3 objects, getKryptonim() is and getter of Rota class just for testing. Instead of restored objects I receive
*'java.lang.String com.firetrap.android.firetrapair.Rota.getKryptonim()' on a null object reference*

Main activity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "FireTrapAir";

private Button mRota1_button;
private Button mRota2_button;
private Button mRota3_button;

private Rota mRota1;
private Rota mRota2;
private Rota mRota3;

private Fragment fragmentR1;
private Fragment fragmentR2;
private Fragment fragmentR3;

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState()");
    outState.putSerializable("ROTA1", mRota1);
    outState.putSerializable("ROTA2", mRota2);
    outState.putSerializable("ROTA3", mRota3);

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate()");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        Rota mRota1 = new Rota();
        Rota mRota2 = new Rota();
        Rota mRota3 = new Rota();


    Fragment fragmentR1 = RotaFragment.newInstance(mRota1);
    Fragment fragmentR2 = RotaFragment.newInstance(mRota2);
    Fragment fragmentR3 = RotaFragment.newInstance(mRota3);

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.r1dane_container, fragmentR1).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.r2dane_container, fragmentR2).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.r3dane_container, fragmentR3).commit();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Rota mRota1 = (Rota) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ROTA1");
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState(): ROTA1" + mRota1.getKryptonim());
        Rota mRota2 = (Rota) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ROTA2");
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState(): ROTA2" + mRota2.getKryptonim());
        Rota mRota3 = (Rota) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ROTA3");
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState(): ROTA3" + mRota3.getKryptonim());
    }
}
```

}

RotaFragment shows Rota class attributes.

Rota class is:

```
public class Rota implements Serializable {
    private UUID mId;
    private String mKryptonim;
    private String mStrazak1;
    private String mStrazak2;
    private String mMiejsceDzialan;
    private String mKanalRadiowy;
    private String mKanalKRG;
    private Integer mCisnienieWejscia;
    private Date mWejscie;

    public Rota() {

        Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

        mId = UUID.randomUUID();
        mWejscie = new Date();
        mKryptonim = "podaj kryptonim";
        mStrazak1 = "strażak1";
        mStrazak2 = "strażak2";
        mMiejsceDzialan = "miejsce działań";
        mKanalRadiowy = "B004";
        mKanalKRG = "KRG 1";
        mCisnienieWejscia = 0;
        mWejscie = localCalendar.getTime();
    }
.... getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Configuration-Changes and https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a

Comment: You should only add the fragments if (`savedInstanceState == null`).

Comment: Honestly speaking I don't get how this Bundle works. I thought that it is never gona be null, cause it gets some values on onCreate(). I don't get why {Rota mRota1 = (Rota) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ROTA1");} generates NullPointerException, when it's invoked always later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** In your activity class, there are 3 class variables

```
private Rota mRota1;
private Rota mRota2;
private Rota mRota3;
```

But in `onCreate()` method, you create 3 local variables which have the same name

```
Rota mRota1 = new Rota();
Rota mRota2 = new Rota();
Rota mRota3 = new Rota();
```

So 3 class variables always null, that why you get the error.

**Solution:** Change your code in activity to

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate()");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mRota1 = new Rota();
        mRota2 = new Rota();
        mRota3 = new Rota();
    } else {
        mRota1 = (Rota) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ROTA1");
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState(): ROTA1" + mRota1.getKryptonim());
        mRota2 = (Rota) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ROTA2");
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState(): ROTA2" + mRota2.getKryptonim());
        mRota3 = (Rota) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("ROTA3");
        Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState(): ROTA3" + mRota3.getKryptonim());
    }

    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragmentR1 = RotaFragment.newInstance(mRota1);
    Fragment fragmentR2 = RotaFragment.newInstance(mRota2);
    Fragment fragmentR3 = RotaFragment.newInstance(mRota3);

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.r1dane_container, fragmentR1).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.r2dane_container, fragmentR2).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.r3dane_container, fragmentR3).commit();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState()");
    outState.putSerializable("ROTA1", mRota1);
    outState.putSerializable("ROTA2", mRota2);
    outState.putSerializable("ROTA3", mRota3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tommy! You're right - it such a stupid begginer's mistake.